# All answers to question deleted

Tags: support

There were several answers and comments to my question at [How can I configure ipython to display integers in hex format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977066/how-can-i-configure-ipython-to-display-integers-in-hex-format), and all of them seem to have been deleted. How can that happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each and every of these has been deleted by their respective writer.

Some have been downvoted (as they were very low quality), so that's probably why they were deleted by their owners.

The other you commented on that it didn't help, so that was probably deleted for that reason.

Coincidence.

Comment: Thanks -- it's the first time I experience something like this.

Comment: There is an answer with 3 upvotes and zero downvotes. No idea why the owner deleted that..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra - The comments claim that it doesn't work. If the owner can verify that, it would be a very good reason to delete the answer. (I once deleted an answer with 7 upvotes for that reason - it was just wrong :-).

Comment: Indeed, none of the answers worked.